# c++ string global variable cannot assign normally

Tags: c++, string, global-variables

I have a global.h like this:

```
#include <string>

extern std::string logPath;
extern std::string logFormat;
extern int maxKeepDays;

class Initializer
{
public:
    Initializer()
    {
        std::cout << "Initializer constructor niftyCounter=" << niftyCounter << " logPath=" << logPath << " maxKeepDays=" << maxKeepDays << " logFormat=" << logFormat << std::endl;
        if (niftyCounter++ == 0)
            init();
    }

    ~Initializer()
    {
        std::cout << "Initializer destructor" << std::endl;
        if (--niftyCounter == 0)
            clean();
    }
private:
    void init();
    void clean();
    static int niftyCounter;
};

static Initializer s_initializer;
```

and global.cpp like this:

```
#include "global.h"
int Initializer::niftyCounter = 0;

int maxKeepDays = 30;
std::string logPath("default logPath");
std::string logFormat("default logFormat");

void Initializer::init()
{

    std::cout << "Initializer init() " << "logPath=" << logPath << " maxKeepDays=" << maxKeepDay << " logFormat=" << logFormat << std::endl;
    
}

void Initializer::clean()
{
    std::cout << "Initializer clean()" << std::endl;

}
```

then I use global.xxx in main.cpp like this:

```
#include "global.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // do something
}
```

I got output like this:

```
Initializer constructor niftyCounter=0 logPath= maxKeepDays=30 logFormat=
Initializer init() logPath= maxKeepDays=30 logFormat=
Initializer destructor
Initializer clean()
```

I found that the integer global variable (such as maxKeepDays) could be assigned normally, but the string variables(logPath and logFormat) are empty. I don't know why it is.

Comment: I think you're running into problems with static initialization order. If you print `logPath` from main you get the correct value I'm guessing?

Comment: Also, note that declaring `static` variables in namespace scope in a header file is normally a very bad idea.

Comment: Note that the OP appears to be trying to implement the nifty/schwartz counter idiom in which case the `static Initializer s_initializer` definition in the header is key to its operation.  The irony being that nifty counters were designed to prevent precisely the initialization order issues that appear to be present here :-(